# Llamada duplicada a 'open' usando mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Buenas, iniciandome en node.js y mongodb me encuentro de primeras con un problema que no se si es tal.

Teniendo el archivos server.js tan simple como

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var dbapi = require("./db/db.js");

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World\n');

    dbapi.connection();
}).listen(port);
```

y db.js con

```
'use strict'
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports.connection = function () {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/protocoloDb", { useMongoClient: true });

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

    db.once('open', function () {
        console.log("Now connected!");
    });
}
```

El resultado en consola es un doble 'Conexión establecida'. ¿No se supone que 'once' debería ejecutarse sólo una vez?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vale, perdón, no vi este artículo antes de publicar la pregunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515200/why-mongoose-opens-two-connections

Moongose usa por debajo el controlador nativo de MongoDB y este, a su vez, usa el pooling de conexiones para la gestión asíncrona. Dicho valor es modificable al crear la conexión usando la opción {server: {poolSize: 2}} en el método createconnection.

Ese valor lo tenía especificado en mi caso a 2, por lo que sacaba en el log de mongo que había dos conexiones abiertas.

Comment: por favor traduce la respuesta y trata de explicarlo , dos dias despues marca valida tu pregunta